# Windows 7 PC's not receiving updates from WSUS Server (Windows 2003 Server)

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, wsus

I have a Windows Server 2003 machine that has been successfully running WSUS for more than two years. Almost all our PCs are running Windows XP and they are getting updates without any problems. We are slowly migrating those Windows XP PCs to Windows 7.

Now my Window 7 PCs are not getting any updates. Is there any known issue with WSUS on Server 2003 that might prevent Windows 7 clients from receiving updates? What else could be preventing updates from being applied?

Comment: What error is seen in WSUS concerning the Windows 7 clients?

Comment: Do you see Windows 7 clients in the WSUS console?  What SP is your WSUS?

Answer (score 2):

Get the Windows Server Update Services 3.0 SP2 from the following location: [Windows Server Update Services 3.0 SP2](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5216)

WSUS 3.0 SP2 delivers important customer-requested management, stability, and performance improvements. Some of the features and improvements include the following:

- Integration with Windows Server 2008 R2.
- Support for the BranchCache feature in Windows Server 2008 R2.
- **Support for Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 clients.**
- Compliance Report
- Windows Update Agent (WUA) offers a collection of performance enhancements, user experience improvements, and bug fixes software updates.